# MPI: Determine hostname of another rank

Tags: mpi

I am working on a custom MPI_Barrier method that shows what node is blocking. To this end I'd like rank 0 to determine the hostname of some rank without communication.

The obvious way would be for rank 0 to gather all hostnames, so it knows where which rank is running, but in case of a barrier the node might have crashed (even in the very beginning) so you cannot use this method.

But somehow each rank must know all how to reach all other ranks (and thus their hostnames), but I have not found a method to find out this information.

Your help would be very much apprechiated.

Comment: you might be able to retrieve this information from the MPI internals, but that would not be portable. If your code crashes before `MPI_Init()`, then you have a quite severe issue you sould be able to troubleshoot with a single MPI task. If not, then do the `MPI_Gather()` once for all right after `MPI_Init()` and you should be fine.

Comment: It's a pitty there seems to be no way to do this...